# VS 2010 C++ local variable debugging

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I am working on a graphic engine with DirectX. I simplified one of my func like this(because it has the same issue):

```
void    foo(int p,int q){ 
 if(!p){
  int a=0; 
  a=4;
 }else{
  int a=0;
  a=5;
 } 
 if(p==1){
  if(q==1){
   float    opacity=0; 
  } 
 } 
} 
 int main(){
  foo(1,2); 
  return 0; 
 }
```

if I call foo(1,2), I cant view values of a in else block in VS Debug panel,but when I call foo(0,2) I can see values of a in if block.It show Symbol 'a' not found bla bla...And when i changed "float opacity=0;" to "float   opacity;" it works well and i can debug it.

I am grouping the objects,meshes and materials according to their properties.Here is my original function:

```
VOID DXACMyApp::LoadSceneFromFile(CHAR  *a_file){
    //File name can not be null
    DXAMIsNull(a_file,DXAE_ERROR_REPORTING_LEVEL_MBOX);
    DXAMIsNull(m_effect,DXAE_ERROR_REPORTING_LEVEL_MBOX);

    //Create Supported Input Layouts

    //1st input layout
    //elements
    D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC    ied_PN[]    =   {
        {"POSITION",    0,DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT,0,0,D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA,0},
        {"NORMAL",      0,DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT,0,12,D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA,0}
    };
    //every pass of same technique must have same layout
    //create input layout
    IDXACRenderGroupIL      *ilGroup_PN =   0;
    DXAMHResult(CreateILGroup(m_effect->GetTechniqueByName("SolidMaterialRender"),ied_PN,2,&ilGroup_PN),DXAE_ERROR_REPORTING_LEVEL_MBOX);
    AddInputLayoutGroup(ilGroup_PN);
    //create technique groups
    IDXACRenderGroupTechnique   *SolidMaterialTechGroup =   0;
    DXAMHResult(CreateTechniqueGroup(m_effect->GetTechniqueByName("SolidMaterialRender"),&SolidMaterialTechGroup),DXAE_ERROR_REPORTING_LEVEL_MBOX);
    //add tech group to il group
    ilGroup_PN->AddTechniqueGroup(SolidMaterialTechGroup);

    Assimp::Importer    importer;
    const   aiScene *scene  =   importer.ReadFile(a_file,aiProcess_CalcTangentSpace|aiProcess_Triangulate|aiProcess_OptimizeMeshes|
    aiProcess_JoinIdenticalVertices|aiProcess_SortByPType|aiProcess_RemoveRedundantMaterials);

    //iterate objects
    for(UINT    i=0 ;   i<scene->mRootNode->mNumChildren    ;   i++){
        aiNode  *object =   scene->mRootNode->mChildren[i];

        D3DXMATRIX  worldMatrix =   ToD3DXMATRIX(object->mTransformation);

        //object's mesh vector
        std::vector<IDXACMesh*> meshes;
        //count known mesh types
        UINT    recognizedMeshCount =   0;

        //iterate object's meshes(materials)
        for(UINT    j=0 ;   j<object->mNumMeshes    ;   j++){
            aiMesh      *mesh       =   scene->mMeshes[ object->mMeshes[j]  ];
            //Test material type
            aiMaterial  *material   =   scene->mMaterials[mesh->mMaterialIndex];
            BOOL    recognized  =   false;
            IDXACMaterial   *newMaterial    =   0;

            if(material->mNumProperties ==  8){
                //materials with 8 properties
                if( strcmp(material->mProperties[0]->mKey.data,"?mat.name")==0          &&
                        strcmp(material->mProperties[1]->mKey.data,"$clr.ambient")==0       &&
                        strcmp(material->mProperties[2]->mKey.data,"$clr.diffuse")==0       &&
                        strcmp(material->mProperties[3]->mKey.data,"$clr.specular")==0      &&
                        strcmp(material->mProperties[4]->mKey.data,"$clr.emissive")==0      &&
                        strcmp(material->mProperties[5]->mKey.data,"$mat.opacity")==0       &&
                        strcmp(material->mProperties[6]->mKey.data,"$mat.bumpscaling")==0   &&
                        strcmp(material->mProperties[7]->mKey.data,"$mat.shadingm")==0  ){

                    FLOAT       opacity,specPower;
                    D3DXCOLOR   diffuse;
                    D3DXCOLOR   specular,ambient,emissive;

                    //get material info
                    specPower   =   1.0f;                                       
                    memcpy(&ambient ,material->mProperties[1]->mData,12);
                    memcpy(&diffuse ,material->mProperties[2]->mData,12);
                    memcpy(&specular,material->mProperties[3]->mData,12);
                    memcpy(&emissive,material->mProperties[4]->mData,12);
                    memcpy(&opacity ,material->mProperties[5]->mData,4);
                    diffuse.a   =   ambient.a   =   specular.a  =   emissive.a  =   opacity;
                    //create material interface
                    std::string matName(material->mProperties[0]->mData,17);
                    DXACMaterialT1  *matInstance    =   0;
                    matInstance =   new DXACMaterialT1(material->mProperties[0]->mData,&diffuse,&specular,&ambient,&emissive,specPower,m_effect);
                    newMaterial     =   matInstance;

                    recognized  =   true;
                    recognizedMeshCount++;
                }

            }else if(material->mNumProperties   ==  10){
                if( strcmp(material->mProperties[0]->mKey.data,"?mat.name")==0          &&
                        strcmp(material->mProperties[1]->mKey.data,"$clr.ambient")==0       &&
                        strcmp(material->mProperties[2]->mKey.data,"$clr.diffuse")==0       &&
                        strcmp(material->mProperties[3]->mKey.data,"$clr.specular")==0      &&
                        strcmp(material->mProperties[4]->mKey.data,"$clr.emissive")==0      &&
                        strcmp(material->mProperties[5]->mKey.data,"$mat.shininess")==0     &&
                        strcmp(material->mProperties[6]->mKey.data,"$mat.shinpercent")==0   &&
                        strcmp(material->mProperties[7]->mKey.data,"$mat.opacity")==0       &&
                        strcmp(material->mProperties[8]->mKey.data,"$mat.bumpscaling")==0   &&  
                        strcmp(material->mProperties[9]->mKey.data,"$mat.shadingm")==0  ){

                    D3DXCOLOR   diffuse;
                    D3DXCOLOR   specular,ambient,emissive;
                    FLOAT       opacity,specPower;

                    memcpy(&ambient ,material->mProperties[1]->mData,12);
                    memcpy(&diffuse ,material->mProperties[2]->mData,12);
                    memcpy(&specular,material->mProperties[3]->mData,12);
                    memcpy(&emissive,material->mProperties[4]->mData,12);
                    memcpy(&specPower   ,material->mProperties[5]->mData,4);                                        
                    memcpy(&opacity     ,material->mProperties[7]->mData,4);
                    diffuse.a   =   ambient.a   =   specular.a  =   emissive.a  =   opacity;

                    std::string matName(material->mProperties[0]->mData,17);
                    DXACMaterialT1  *matInstance    =   new DXACMaterialT1(matName.substr(4,matName.npos).c_str(),&diffuse,&specular,&ambient,&emissive,specPower,m_effect);
                    newMaterial     =   matInstance;

                    recognized  =   true;
                    recognizedMeshCount++;
                }
            }   
            if(recognized){
                //create mesh instance
                DXACMeshT1      *newMesh    =   new DXACMeshT1(m_d3dDeviceContext);

                //fill vertex buffer desc
                D3D11_BUFFER_DESC   vbd;
                vbd.ByteWidth           =   mesh->mNumVertices*sizeof(VERTEXT1);
                vbd.BindFlags           =   D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
                vbd.CPUAccessFlags      =   0;
                vbd.MiscFlags           =   0;
                vbd.StructureByteStride =   0;
                vbd.Usage               =   D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE;
                //create vertex buffer memory block and subres. data
                VERTEXT1    *vbMemBlock =   new VERTEXT1[mesh->mNumVertices];
                for(UINT    i=0;    i<mesh->mNumVertices    ;   i++){
                    vbMemBlock[i]   =   VERTEXT1(mesh->mVertices[i],mesh->mNormals[i]);
                }
                D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA  vbSrd;
                vbSrd.pSysMem   =   vbMemBlock;
                DXAMHResult(m_d3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&vbd,&vbSrd,&newMesh->m_vertexBuffer),DXAE_ERROR_REPORTING_LEVEL_MBOX);
                newMesh->m_vertexCount  =   mesh->mNumVertices;
                newMesh->m_vertexStride =   sizeof(VERTEXT1);

                //fill index buffer desc
                //only triangles are valid as face
                D3D11_BUFFER_DESC   ibd;
                ibd.ByteWidth           =   mesh->mNumFaces*3*sizeof(DWORD);
                ibd.BindFlags           =   D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
                ibd.CPUAccessFlags      =   0;
                ibd.MiscFlags           =   0;
                ibd.StructureByteStride =   0;
                ibd.Usage               =   D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE;
                //create index buffer memory block and subres. data
                DWORD   *ibMemBlock =   new DWORD[mesh->mNumFaces*3];
                for(UINT    i=0,j=0;    i<mesh->mNumFaces   ;   i++){
                    aiFace  &face   =   mesh->mFaces[i];
                    if(face.mNumIndices!=3){
                        OutputDebugString("Ignoring face");
                        ibMemBlock[j++] =   0;
                        ibMemBlock[j++] =   0;
                        ibMemBlock[j++] =   0;
                    }else{
                        ibMemBlock[j++] =   face.mIndices[0];
                        ibMemBlock[j++] =   face.mIndices[1];
                        ibMemBlock[j++] =   face.mIndices[2];
                    }
                }
                D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA  ibSrd;
                ibSrd.pSysMem   =   ibMemBlock;
                DXAMHResult(m_d3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&ibd,&ibSrd,&newMesh->m_indexBuffer),DXAE_ERROR_REPORTING_LEVEL_MBOX);
                newMesh->m_indexCount   =   mesh->mNumFaces*3;


                IDXACMesh       *imesh  =   newMesh;
                imesh->Release();

            }else{

                //not recognized material
                OutputDebugString("Ignoring mesh");
                return;
            }
        }


    }
    ReleaseCOM(SolidMaterialTechGroup);
    ReleaseCOM(ilGroup_PN);
}
```

Comment: I haven't seen `VOID` in decades. Congratulations.

Comment: No wonders that you spent whole hour debugging, if that is a simplified version of your function

Comment: Hmm... this exact function showed all the expected variables just fine under my VS2010 debugger. Could you be more specific as to what _exactly_ did you do?

Comment: If you're building with optimizations on, I think it would be possible for the compiler to optimize out the `else` statement since in your example function it can _never_ be run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug in VS 2010.I just installed VS SP1 and I can debug any variable without modifying code.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the else, is outside the scope of the variables you are interested in.
move the variables to the top of the function and they will have function scope,
allowing you to see them in the debugger for the scope of the entire function

```
void    foo(int p,int q)
{ 
   int a = 0;               // Move them here
   float opacity = 3.1415f; // And here

   if(!p)
   {
      a=4;
   }
   else
   {
      a=5;
   } 

   if(p==1)
   {
     if(q==1)
     {
         opacity=0; 
     } 
   } 
} 

int main()
{
  foo(1,2); 
  return 0; 
}
```